# How to create class matrix and write functions performed on Matrix in c++

Tags: c++

write function(method) definition of method given above keep it simple because I am beginner.

```
void set()

void set(int)

void set(int ,int)

void set(int ,int ,int)

void set(const Matrix &)
    
void print()const
        
int isSqrMatrix()const

int isNullMatrix()const

int isUnitMatrix()const

int isIdentityMatrix()const

int isSymeticMatrix()const

int Equals(const Matrix)const
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ji8n.jpg)

write function(method) definition of method given above keep it simple because I am beginner.

Comment: **Stack Overflow is not a coding service for ordering code.** Refer to [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and take a [SO tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Show us what you've tried so far and what problem you're facing with that so that we can find out the problem and suggest a correction(if any) and maybe even provide a better solution.

Comment: A [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) might help. Also see [C++ Matrix Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2076624/c-matrix-class)

Comment: How do you get to Carnegie Hall?